# I'm trying to figure out how to reverse a word like java to avaj using substring and by using a scanner for input but can't grasp how to use substring

Tags: java

So if I try to use substring like String a = word.substring(6,3) it will give an error bc you aren't allowed to put your start at the of a end of word and end at the beginning of a word and this is what i have so far which isn't much because I've stumped for a day and half

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word, wordTwo;

    
    System.out.println("enter a word");

    while (true) {

      word = input.next();

      if(word.matches(".*[0-9].*")){

        System.out.println("Please enter a valid word!");

        continue;

      }

      break;

    }
    String a = word.substring();

    System.out.println(a);

    input.close();

  }

}
```

I tried but brute forcing like what I said above but substring doesn't go that way and substring has to be included which is the only problem I'm having and im expecting to type in whatever word and then it spits out that word reverse and instead nothing pops out because I barely know what I'm doing.

Comment: [StringBuffer:reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#reverse--)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringBuilder.reverse()`

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");

    String word = scan.next();
    String reversed = reverse(word);

    System.out.println("Reversed word: " + reversed);
}

public static String reverse(String str) {
    return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
}
```

On the other hand, you can use `char[]`:

```java
public static String reverse(String str) {
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0, j = str.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        char tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }

    return new String(arr).intern();
}
```

Or you can use string concatenation in loop (which gives you less performance)

```java
public static String reverse(String str) {
    String res = "";

    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        res += str.charAt(i);

    return res;
}
```

or this:

```java
public static String reverse(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        str = str.substring(1, str.length() - i)
                + str.charAt(0)
                + str.substring(str.length() - i);
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a word:");
        String word = input.next();

        String reversed = "";

        for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reversed += word.substring(i, i + 1);
        }

        System.out.println("Reversed word: " + reversed);

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using str.substring(a,b) will return a substring that contains the indexed [a,b) segment of the original string. Reversing the indexes used in the substring() function will not create a reversed string for you.